# ¿Que error tengo en mi código para que no me este mostrando mi Tabla? AngularJS + ASP.net

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net

**Tengo todo mi proyecto y no me muestra los datos los datos que agregue en mi *Controlador* en la imagen me muestra de esa manera {{}}**

**CONTROLADOR**

```
 public JsonResult GetEmployees()
        {
            List<Employee> empList = new List<Employee>();

            Employee emp = new Employee { FirstName = "James", LastName = "Bond", Country = "Germany" };
            empList.Add(emp);

            emp = new Employee { FirstName = "Roy", LastName = "Agasthyan", Country = "United States" };
            empList.Add(emp);

            return Json(new { employees = empList });
        }
```

**MODELO:**

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

**VISTA:**

```
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular .NET MVC 4";

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'HomeCtrl/GetEmployees'
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.employees = response.data.employees;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }]);
</script>
</head>



<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <h2>
            {{message}}
        </h2>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="bs-example marginTop50" data-example-id="table-within-panel">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3>Code Handbook</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>
                            AngularJS ASP.NET MVC Editable Grid Demo
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>
                                    #
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    First Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Last Name
                                </th>
                                <th>
                                    Country
                                </th>
                                <th>

                                </th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                                <th scope="row">
                                    {{$index+1}}
                                </th>
                                <td>
                                    {{emp.FirstName}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{emp.LastName}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {{emp.Country}}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al presionar F12 me muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estas utilizando el servicio `$http` fuera del controlador y tampoco estas injectando el servicio $http al controlador:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular .NET MVC 4";

}]);
// esta afuera, deberia de ser adentro
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'Home/GetEmployees'
}).then(function (response) {
        $scope.employees = response.data.employees;
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
});
```

Tu codigo deberia de ser:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.message = "Welcome to Angular .NET MVC 4";

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'Home/GetEmployees'
    })
        .then(function (response) {
            $scope.employees = response.data.employees;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
    });
}]);
```

Comment: aun nada, no entiendo el porque no funciona

Comment: Abre la consola presionando F12 en chrome y dime el error que muestra.

Comment: no me muestra los errores..

Comment: Mas abajo se ve un tap que se llama console, al lado de What's New, dale clic y mira si hay algun error.

Comment: que tal ves. consejo ?}

Comment: hola, me ayudas ?